# What direction to walk in to capture a targeted Pokemon?

Tags: pokemon-go

There is a list of the nearby Pokemon and some approximate idea of the distance. But after I choose one, how do I actually walk towards it? Is there a way to see the Pokemon on the map or some direction indicator to follow?

Comment: I believe that if you pay attention to the map closely, every now and then you will see leaves rustling; this is a wild pokemon

Comment: The leaves do not indicate that there *is* a pokemon there, only that there is a higher chance of one spawning in that region.

Answer (score 5):

The game, as of now, does not have a builtin direction indicator.

You can use the footsteps to determine which way is approximately the right way to go (if the count gets larger, you're going in the wrong direction), but the game is intentionally vague on this front.

Comment: I wonder what the optimal directions and distances would be. I've only ever managed to find one using the footsteps next to a beach (halving the possible directions). In my opininion the system is too glitchy to be useful, if I reload the app I get very different pokemon showing in the nearby, which means that information is outdated for some reason.

Comment: After a few days of testing, you can track a Pokemon and the tracker will pulse green if you are walking in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you want to track a specific Pokemon listed in the bottom right ''Nearby'' area:

1. Bring up the list.
2. Click which one you want to track/find.
3. Whenever you are facing and/or walking TOWARDS the Pokemon, every so often there will be a SMALL green border "pulse" animation from the rounded rectangle that's indicating how far away it is.
   THIS is how you can know if you are going in the right direction or not. 
   ((I'm 100% certain of this.))

Also, though listed by closest to furthest in the popped up nearby window, when minimized it seems to re-order them based on what direction you are facing and/or which direction you are currently travelling in.
((Not 100% certain, but it seems this way from observations.))

Comment: I'd love to see a source for this- my bar pulses every now and then even when standing still. For me, it seems to pulse whenever a new pokemon is added to, or changes position in the nearby panel.

Comment: Nope -- from *my* personal experience, I picked a particular pokemon and started walking in a given direction. The bar pulsed. I turned around and walked the exact opposite direction. The bar pulsed.